# Passing data between components into React (props)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, parameter-passing, react-props, prop

Into `DisplayVisit component` I have displayed data:

```
<div>
{(this.state.allVisit.length > 0) ? this.state.allVisit.map(data => {

    return (
        <div key={data.id} className="card-header mb-2" style={{ background: "#F0F3F7" }}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label><b>VisitName:</b> {data.dataContext.VisitName} &nbsp;</label>
             </div>                                                     
                                                    
            <div className="form-group">
                <Link to={`/visit/${data.id}`} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >
                    <i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-right" /> Details
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    }) : (
        <div className="card-header p-3 mb-2 text-black">
            <label><b>Empty</b></label>
        </div>
     )
}

</div>
```

When user click **Details** is moved to next component `VisitDetails` - this is working.

**App.js**

```
<Route exact path="/visit/:id" component={VisitDetails}/>
```

Then I want have access to `id` and `data.dataContext`:

```
class VisitDetails extends Component {

    render() {

        const { id } = this.props;
        const { data.dataContext } = this.props;
        //or const {data} = this.prop

        return (
            <div>
                {id}, {data.dataContext.VisitName}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

but I'm doing something wrong. Im just learning and try to dev first app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DetailVisit component :

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/visit/${data.id}`, state: { data: data.dataContext.VisitName} }} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
   <i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-right" /> Details
</Link>
```

In your VisitDetails.js :

```
class VisitDetails extends Component {

    render() {

        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        const { data } = this.props.location.state;

        return (
            <div>
                {id}, {data}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, pleast try it and tell me if there are errors

Comment: id is fine, but data no: `Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'this.props.location.state' as it is undefined.`

Comment: I had to restart and now is fine. But it's possible to pass my all `data.dataContext ` ?

Comment: yes you just have to put this ```state: { data: data.dataContext } }}```